# Why can't narbar-btn be used on <a> within navbar-nav in bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

The official bootstrap 3 docs state:

> Context-specific usage
>
> Like the standard button classes, .navbar-btn can be used on  and  elements. However, neither .navbar-btn nor the standard button classes should be used on  elements within .navbar-nav.

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-buttons

Does anyone know why this is the case?